# Absolute Import in Python

Tags: python, python-import

I am having a really hard time understanding absolute imports in Python. I would appreciate any help!

I am using Python 3.10.5 (currently the latest release) for reference.

Now suppose this is my directory:

```
project
├── __init__.py
└── package1
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── subpackage1
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── foo.py
    └── subpackage2
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── bar.py
        └── subpackage2A
            ├── __init__.py
            └── foo_bar.py

project2
├── __init__.py
└── ...  
    ├── __init__.py
    └── tom.py
```

Additionally, suppose `foo.py` contains this function:

```
def foo_func():
  print('in foo.py')
```

Now here are my questions:

1. How do I import `foo.py` and use `foo_func` inside `foo_bar.py`, using absolute import?
2. How do I import `foo.py` and use `foo_func` inside `bar.py`, using absolute import?
3. Is it possible to import `foo_bar.py` and use `foo_func` inside `tom.py`?

I would appreciate it if you could elaborate on your answer. Thank you!

Comment: Your package has to be installed, or otherwise on the PYTHONPATH. Do you have a setup.py or something similar to install it?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [relative import](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports) within your package/project

I think for your sample it would be something like

```
#foo_bar.py
from ...subpackage1.foo import foo_func

#bar.py
from ..subpackage1.foo import foo_func
```

for the tom.py, because is in other project, that project need to be reachable by the regular import mechanism (like adding those to your PYTHONPATH), or you can do the relative import if you're certain that they will always be together

Comment: The OP specifically asked how to do this with absolute imports, not relative imports.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the base directory containing `project` and `project2` is in `sys.path` (e.g. because you used `setup.py` to install said projects into user or system `site-packages` with that directory structure, or you did something hacky with `PYTHONPATH`, or the script itself modifies `sys.path` in hacky ways), the answer to all three questions is the same:

The source file that wants to call `foo_func` would contain the line `import project.package1.subpackage1.foo`, and could call `project.package1.subpackage1.foo.foo_func()`, or it could do `from project.package1.subpackage1.foo import foo_func` and call `foo_func` unqualified (it could also use `from project.package1.subpackage1 import foo` and do `foo.foo_func()` or use `as ANYNAME` to simplify the non-`from` import or alias either import).

The answer is the same because that's the whole point of absolute imports; they're absolute. As long as the directory containing `project` is in `sys.path` before any other directory containing a `project` directory (or if that other `project` directory omits `__init__.py` files to remain an implicit namespace package, or includes `__init__.py` files with the hacks to be an explicit namespace package) `project.package1.subpackage1.foo` is the absolute path available to *any* Python module that wishes to import it.

Answer (score 0):

When importing something, Python will look in these folders in this order:

1. directory of the Python script that was originally executed
2. standard library
3. external libraries that have been installed

Which file are you initially executing? If you're executing "project/__init__.py", you should be able to to something like `import package1.subpackage1`